# Are there any type constructors which are *not* functors?

Tags: type-theory, category-theory, haskell

So I'm almost done teaching myself category theory. One of the main take-aways for me is that type constructors (higher-kinded types) are endo-functors.

But it this *always* the case? What's throwing me off is Haskell's `Functor` typeclass:

```
class Functor f :: * -> * where
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

If all type constructors were *a priori* functors, there would be no need to define a special type-class. But I can't think of any type-constructors that fail to satisfy the `Functor` type-class: product, sum, function, list, set, option, etc.

I also cannot imagine the utility of a type-constructors that is "one-half" of a functor, i.e. it has a map from objects to objects, but no map between morphisms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One obvious counterexample is a binary search tree. You cannot freely substitute the values in a binary search tree because a substitution might change the ordering (relative to `Ord`), or even replace the values with a type which is not an instance of `Ord` at all.

A possibly less-obvious example is a *contravariant* endofunctor. Consider:

```
data Tricky a = Tricky (a -> String)
```

Try writing a `Functor` instance for this.

But that doesn't mean you can't construct a functor-like class which it the type does satisfy. This `Tricky` type, after all, is a contravariant functor:

```
-- Somebody has probably already implemented this in a library
-- somewhere, with a better name.
class ContraFunctor f :: * -> * where
    contramap :: (b -> a) -> (f a -> f b)

instance ContraFunctor Tricky where
    contramap f (Tricky t) = Tricky (t . f)
```

and like `fmap`, it must satisfy some axioms which are left as an exercise.

What's interesting, though, is that you can usually come up with a functor-like class (and its axioms, of course) which applies type substitutions in a principled way, from the *types* of the functions which comprise their API.

The full details are beyond the scope, but it's based on a remarkable property of a polymorphic function is known as the ["free theorem"](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf). Any polymorphic function has a theorem that it satisfies simply by virtue of being polymorphic, and the theorem is mechanically derivable from its type.

What the theorem essentially states is that a polymorphic function commutes with a type substitution. This is what "polymorphic" really means.

Let's take `reverse` as an example:

```
reverse :: forall a. [a] -> [a]
```

There are no constraints whatsoever on the type of `a`, so it will commute with any type substition:

```
forall f :: A -> B. fmap f . reverse = reverse . fmap f
```

(Remember, `.` is function composition in Haskell.)

This is true for any types `A` and `B`. In a deep sense, this is what the "forall" actually means in the type of `reverse`.

Now consider `sort`:

```
sort :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

The problem here is that `Ord` is a constraint on the type of `a`. What this means is that this is a constraint on any type substitution: it must be a homomorphism of `Ord`.

```
forall f :: A -> B.
    (forall x y : A, compare x y = compare (f x) (f y))
    => fmap f . sort = sort . fmap f
```

That extra precondition, that `f` is an `Ord`-homomorphism, intuitively means that `f` is a function which preserves the order. This should make sense: if a type substitution doesn't change the ordering of elements, then that type substitution commutes with `sort`.

But here's my favourite example of all. Suppose that `F` and `G` are functors. Now consider this function:

```
eta :: forall a. F a -> G a
```

The free theorem of this function is:

```
forall f : A -> B.  fmap f . eta = eta . fmap f
```

Note that the two `fmap`s are different instances; the first one is the instance for `G` and the second is the instance for `F`. What this is saying is that `eta`, *by virtue of its type alone*, is a natural transformation.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed response! 1. For the binary search tree constructor `BST a`, I don't think this is a counter-example, because it's not actually a type-constructor. A type-constructor has to be defined on *every* type; limiting the domain to ordered types precludes this. 2. A contravariant functor is just a normal covariant functor in the dual category, so while technically this is a counter-example, it's not a very interesting one.  3. You're talking about natural transformations. This fact very recently blew my mind. 4. I am going to read the paper you linked

Comment: In Haskell, `BST` could be a generalised algebraic datatype. GADTs allow type constructors to be qualified with constraints such as `Ord`. See https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint

Comment: How do GADTs fit into category theory, if at all?

Comment: Well enough. They have an obvious Church encoding representation, so in that sense they don't really introduce anything new.

Comment: Having said all that, I would say that the one thing that complicates the relationship between Haskell and category theory is that types are passed implicitly in Haskell, where they are explicit in, say, System F.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing: Understanding the parametricity theorem is probably the one thing that made me "get" what a natural transformation is. What makes a natural transformation "natural", from a Haskell perspective, is that you can't write a function which behaves differently based on the value of any "elements" in a `Functor`.  So `reverse`, whatever it does, could behave differently given a different list "backbone", it can't behave differently given the same "backbone" but with different elements in it.

Comment: Implicit type parameters always bothered me in Haskell and SML. Having to explicitly instantiate the polymorphic function with a specific type makes it much clearer what's going on. However, I think we can assume that is being done "under the hood" with type inference. With regards to your second comment, to me the intuition goes the other way; understanding what a natural transformation was made me "get" polymorphic functions. I mean, I understood them before, but category theory showed them in a new light.