# Do all covariant type constructors F[+A] form a functor?

Tags: type-theory

Do all covariant type constructors (using scala notation) F[+A] form a functor? If so, is there a proof of that? If not, what is a counterexample?

The related [Are there any type constructors which are *not* functors?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64584/are-there-any-type-constructors-which-are-not-functors) is about all type constructors, not just covariant ones.